# PHP preg_replace between 2 delimiters

Tags: php, regex

Hi I am trying to replace `,` with `|` from a long string with in braces `[]` but the following seems to be failed.

Here is the string.

> ID: 3a0dd504341fb10a055xxxxxx, time: Wed Feb 01 12:54:39 EST 2012, client: 10.192.34.13, user: User [ID: 1456xcvererwe, session ID: sdfweerwer234325433 ], action: USER_ACTION_ITEM, action id: 36014, result: FAIL, reason: USER_EXCEPTION, arguments: [abcd, test12 , testing ]

Here is what I want as output.

> ID: 3a0dd504341fb10a055xxxxxx, time: Wed Feb 01 12:54:39 EST 2012, client: 10.192.34.13, user: User [ID: 1456xcvererwe | session ID: sdfweerwer234325433 ], action: USER_ACTION_ITEM, action id: 36014, result: FAIL, reason: USER_EXCEPTION, arguments: [abcd | test12 | testing ]

I tried following

```
$text = preg_replace("/(^[)(.*)(])/U","|",$text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
$text = 'ID: 3a0dd504341fb10a055xxxxxx, time: Wed Feb 01 12:54:39 EST 2012, client: 10.192.34.13, user: User [ID: 1456xcvererwe, session ID: sdfweerwer234325433 ], action: USER_ACTION_ITEM, action id: 36014, result: FAIL, reason: USER_EXCEPTION, arguments: [abcd, test12 , testing ]';

function rep($r){
    return "[". preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/',' | ', $r[1]). "]";
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[([^\]]+)\]/i', 'rep', $text);
```

Comment: Hi Shiplu,  Thanks a lot.  it worked, Just one quick question if I want to replace : as well within [ ] can u please let me know the syntax. ?

Comment: use `'/\s*[:,]\s*/'` instead of `'/\s*,\s*/'`

Comment: @harishom There is a tick mark bellow the voting arrows. Click it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to learn.